# layoutAttributesForElementsInRect - nil vs. []

Tags: swift, uikit

`UICollectionViewLayout`'s `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` has an `Optional` return type: `[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?`. If there are no layout attributes in the specified rect, for one reason or another, in what situations should I return `[]`, and in one situations should I return `nil`?